# How to add classes from a selector string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have several CSS classes in the form of a selector, for example `.myclass.myclass2` and I want to apply both classes to an element.

I could `.split()` the string and apply each class with `.addClass()`, but before I do, I'd like to know if there's a "native" jQuery function to do this kind of thing or if someone has written a function to handle it.

To better explain: I want a function that I can pass it a CSS selector and it'll add the classes to an element. Like `$('#myelem').addClass('.myclass.myclass')`.

(I would also love it to handle other CSS selectors such as `#myid`, but I fear that's asking too much and I'd probably need a full parser function.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this to your script:

```
$.fn.oldAddClass = $.fn.addClass;
$.fn.addClass = function(x){
    if(typeof x == 'string'){
        this.oldAddClass(x.replace(/\./g, ' '));
    }else{
        this.oldAddClass(x);
    }
}
```

Then call `addClass()` with your dot :

```
$(el).addClass('.class1.class2');
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/8hBDr/

Comment: This is **exactly** what I wanted. I bet if I extended it to strip out any ID tags or other non-class CSS selectors, it'd be perfect. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean? Like when doing `addClass('#id.class')` it add the class `class`? to the element?

Comment: Yep. Also I found a bug: you need to `return this.oldAddClass()`.

Comment: Oh yeah, i alway forgot to return it.

Comment: Here the code for striping id's http://jsfiddle.net/433aF/. For dom element, I can remove it though else its would mess up old addclass function.

Comment: Thanks. Couldn't you use regex to locate any IDs instead of looping through it?

Comment: I am not really good with RegExp, maybe you can find a way to do it, but looping was the easiest way for me to replace it.

Answer (score 3):

`addClass` takes a space separated string, so all you need to do is replace dots with spaces:

```
var classes = '.myclass.myclass2';
$(element).addClass(classes.replace(/\./g,' ').trim()))
```

Comment: A better way of doing `.split()`, so I'll do this if I need to go in that direction. My question though is if there's a way _without_ doing so.

Comment: Well, jQuery expects space separated string. That's the format you need to pass in. There's no other way unless you re-use this format from the start.

Comment: Someone needs to write a library that takes a selector and returns it broken up into IDs, classes and whatever else in the selector that could be used.

Comment: Why? jQuery already does that and returns a collection of elements. I think you're turning this into an XY problem... Adding classes doesn't have anything to do with selectors, that's why there's no dot, you're basically doing: `element.className += ' '+class`

Comment: Yeah, I admit, I am turning it into an XY problem. Thanks for helping me realise it. :)

Answer (score 1):

create two classes inside style tag like this

```
        .a {
       backgroud-color:red;
       }
     .b{
       color:blue; 
       }
      </style>
```

now add your jquery codes

then inside javascript code

```
       <script type="text/javascript">

       $(document).ready(function(){

      $('#mydiv').addClass(a).addCLass(b);
```

or

```
     $("#mydiv").addClass({a,b});
```

or

```
      $('#mydiv').addClass(a);
  $('#mydiv').addClass(b);



     });
     </script>
```

here is the html

```
          <html>
       <body>
                 <div id="mydiv"></div>
              </body>
                  </html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot add css selectors (like `#elemid.myclass`) directly to an element in native `jQuery`. The example below shows how to add multiple classes using a space delimited string.

```
$(elem).addClass("myclass mycalss2")
```

And the documentation:
http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

Comment: I already acknowledged this possible method. My question is if I can do it _without_ using `.addClass()`.

Comment: Why do you not want to use .addClass()? It allows you to add multiple classes in a space separated string.

Comment: It means I have to convert my selector string into a space delimited string. If there's a way to do it without doing this, I'd prefer to use it.

Comment: There's really no point in creating your version of `addClass`. I don't understand your concern. This is the format jQuery decided to use because the dot refers to selectors no class names. It makes sense. What's the point of changing this behavior when you can just format your string to be used by jQuery?